# Is it possible to invoke OpenGL without a display?

Tags: nvidia, opengl, docker, headless

In order to use continuous integration on an application that depends on OpenGL, I would like to be able to use GLX in an ubuntu docker container. I don't care about the application's rendered output; the tests are purely on high-level math.

I'm using the latest ubuntu image from the docker repository, which is 14.04. I thought I could use an Xdummy display. I've installed the packages and then run the Xdummy display:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime nvidia-304
Xorg -noreset +extension GLX +extension RANDR +extension RENDER -logfile ./10.log -config ./xorg.conf :10
```

However, this gets stuck on loading glx. The log file says:

```
[  1195.648] (EE) Failed to initialize GLX extension (Compatible NVIDIA X driver not found)
[  1195.658] (II) XKB: reuse xkmfile /var/lib/xkb/server-B20D7FC79C7F597315E3E501AEF10E0D866E8E92.xkm
[  1195.662] (II) config/udev: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0) card0 /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[  1195.662] (II) config/udev: Ignoring already known drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
```

Is this a case of a missing package, or is there something fundamentally impossible with what I'm trying to do?